# Material UI Tooltip not rendering on nested components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nested-tooltip-9702e?file=/src/index.js

The tooltip shows up for the second Avatar, but not the first one. How can I get it to show up for the first one?

I would like to nest the tooltip component inside another, and I believe the issue lies somewhere in forwarding Refs, however I don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the icon with a `span` or `div` or may be `p`

```
<Tooltip title={displayText} placement="top">
  <span>
    <SupportingIcon />
  </span>
</Tooltip>
```

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nested-tooltip-forked-5okxh)